# Does the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n+1}{n^3+10n}$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Using the ratio test, we evaluate:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left| \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right| = \lim_{n \to \infty}\left| \frac{(n+1) + 1}{(n+1)^3 + 10(n+1)} \cdot \frac{n^3+10n}{n+1} \right| = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left| \frac{n^4 + 2n^3 + 10n^2 + 20n}{(n+1)^4 + 10(n+1)^2} \right|$$
$$ < \lim_{n \to \infty} \left| \frac{n^4 + 2n^3 + 10n^2 + 20n}{n^4 + 10n^2} \right| = 1$$

Hence $\lim_{n \to \infty} \left| \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right| < 1$ and the series converges.

Is this an appropriate solution?

Comment: No. The critical step (the $<$ step) in your proof is not obvious; in fact, it is false and both limits are $1$. You need to use the comparison test against $\frac{1}{n^2}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We observe first that
$$
\frac{n+1}{n^3+10n}\le \frac{n+1}{n^3+n}=\frac{1}{n^2},
$$
and as the series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2},
$$
converges, so does the series $\,\,\,\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n+1}{n^3+10n}$.

Answer (score 4):

You can't conclude using the ratio test since the limit is $1$. Notice that

$$a_n\sim_\infty \frac1{n^2}$$
and the Riemann series  $\sum\frac1{n^2}$ is convergent so the given series is convergent by comparison.

Answer (score 4):

The series is bounded above by
$$\sum \frac{n + 1}{n^3} = \sum \frac{1}{n^2} + \sum \frac{1}{n^3},$$
so by the comparison test the series converges because both sums on the right-hand side are convergent $p$-series.

Answer (score 3):

*Hint*. You may use the comparison test, writing
$$
\frac{n+1}{n^3+10n}=\frac{1+\frac1n}{n^2+10}\sim \frac{1}{n^2}
$$ as $n$ tends to $+\infty$ and conclude easily.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n+1}{n^3+10n} \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n+n}{n^3} =  2 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} < \infty.
$$